# Array items sorting in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that will change in its sorting order of items after each and every call but I wanted them to be fixed as per my requirement on the client side. Example attached below.

array, for example, the indexes or the sorting order won't be the same, it changes every time

```js
[
    {
        key: "foo"
    },
    {
        key: "bar"
    },
    {
        key: "baz"
    }
]
```

and this is what I want every time, no matter what the sorting order is.

```js
[
    {
        key: "baz"
    },
    {
        key: "foo"
    },
    {
        key: "bar"
    }
]
```

Comment: As I see, there is no particular order on the pairs. Add a priority or order key to each pair. So that you can sort based on that.

Comment: basically, the objects are coming from s3 bucket

Comment: I'm using s3 as storage and getting the document objects.

Comment: Are those constant values? If it's dynamic, it is not possible to update priority if many such key pairs are present. May be you have to keep a separate table with priorities and update the keys based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Define the "priority" of every key in an object pre hand. Then, using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), reorder the array:

```js
const priorities = { baz: 3, foo: 2, bar: 1 };

const reorder = (arr = []) =>
  arr.sort(({ key: a }, { key: b }) => priorities[b] - priorities[a]);

console.log( reorder([ { key: "foo" }, { key: "bar" }, { key: "baz" } ]) );
console.log( reorder([ { key: "bar" }, { key: "foo" }, { key: "baz" } ]) );
console.log( reorder([ { key: "baz" }, { key: "bar" }, { key: "foo" } ]) );
```